# Plot.ly, TypeScript and ScatterData

Tags: typescript, plotly, plotly.js

I want to create a scatter plot in an Angular application using plot.ly .

All the examples on line use non-typed objects, like so:

```
var trace = {
    x: [1, 2, 3],
    y: [4, 5, 6],
    . . .
}
```

I can do that, but since I'm using TypeScript, I want to use the types defined in `@types/plotly.js` . One of them is `ScatterData`, which is defined as follows (I removed most of the fields, for brevity):

```
export type Data = Partial<ScatterData>;

export interface ScatterData {
    type: 'bar' | 'scatter' | 'scattergl' | 'scatter3d';
    x: Datum[] | Datum[][];
    y: Datum[] | Datum[][];
    z: Datum[] | Datum[][] | Datum[][][];
    xaxis: string;
    yaxis: string;
    ...
}
```

Here is something I'm trying to do that fails:

```
const data: Plotly.Data = {
    type: 'scatter',
    x: [],
    y: [],
};

data.x.push(12);
```

I get an error on the call to push, `TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature`. Trying to place at type guard

```
if(data.x instanceof Ploty.Datum[]) ...
```

fails because it says the property Datum does not exist.

I can make everything work by not specifying `Plotly.Data`, but it's really something I want to resort to.

Answer (score 1):

That compile error is a bit odd, but I think the issue is that the `data.x` property is typed to `Datum[] | Datum[][]`, which means it has *two* different call signatures: `push(Datum)` and `push(Datum[])`. Without an assertion or type-guard somewhere, the compiler can't verify that `push(12)` is correct. If you add an assertion it should work:

```
(data.x as Plotly.Datum[]).push(12);
```

Something else to point out, even if you don't annotate `data` as `Plotly.Data`, if you assign `data` to something which is typed to `Plotly.Data` then the type-checker will make sure it's correct. The only down-side is that you won't get IDE type suggestions when you build your `data` object, but you'll get compile errors if you build it incorrectly.